# Random black dot on the screen

Tags: screen, bumblebee

black dots, or more something like this _-, apprear on my screen, but only in windows, not on the side bar. It is very anoying since it apprear every 30 sec and sometime every 5 sec in row.
I have bumblebee installed. It may be related.

Here is a screeshot :
[image]

Comment: You don't have this issue on windows or any other operating system, using that graphics card and monitor?

Comment: Had Windows 8 once, no issue at all.

Comment: okay, that issue looks like as if it's a unity issue, or something of the likes, because the top bar and the launcher seem to be fine... it seems that only the window has a problem. Is this only with chromium? Or is this with any application?

Comment: Any application. Getting used to it...

Comment: Try installing LXDE (lubuntu-desktop), use that (change the session in the login screen), and then see if you still have the same issue. If you don't, we can conclude that the issue is a problem of unity, or something that unity uses that LXDE doesn't (may it be GNOME 3, Compiz, Nux, or anything else).