# Blinking black pattern of dots and lines on the screen

Tags: unity, graphics, bug-reporting, visual-artifacts

There is a black pattern of dots and lines blinking randomly on my screen. It appears randomly, sometimes every 30 seconds, sometimes it doesn't occur at all for a week or so. I had this issue for several months now, both in 13.04 and 13.10.

It looks more or less like the screenshot this gentleman has taken, although the pattern is different:

[Random black dot on the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313190/random-black-dot-on-the-screen)

It seems to be linked to mouse pointer movement. In rare cases, the pattern stays on the screen if I happen to stop moving the mouse or scrolling at the right moment. As soon as I move the mouse or scroll, the pattern vanishes.

I managed to take some screenshots, but I'm not sure how to upload them here.

I run 13.10 (64) on an Intel IvyBridge Mobile.

EDIT: New drivers seem to have done the trick.

EDIT: The problem persists. Back to square one.

Comment: So far, the problem occurred with Firefox (several versions) and Chromium. It does not occur when I run fullscreen wine applications.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this issue is to install intel graphics driver.
Here's How:

1. Goto this [link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2) and download the .dep package suitable for your OS version (eg. Linux Graphics Installer for Ubuntu* 13.04, 64-bit)
2. Install the signatures listed on the above link (warning there are two types - one for Ubuntu and another one for Fedora)
3. Double click on the .dep package you have downloaded in the first step
4. Double clicking the .dep package will start up Software center. wait a few second for it to load the Installation program
5. Click Install
6. After the installation has been completed, reboot your machine.

If this answer is the solution, please mark it as your accepted answer.
Thank you, and hope this helps :)

Comment: So far it happened with Firefox (several versions) and Chromium. It does not occur when I run fullscreen wine applications.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what could be the problem, can you tell me what graphics card are you using. And also did this issue happened right when you started using the Ubuntu OS or did it like happened randomly out of no where

Comment: It's the integrated graphics module that comes with the IvyBridge Core i5. I started using Ubuntu 12.10 on this machine and I didn't have that problem then. If my memory serves me right, it started some time after upgrading to 13.04.

Comment: PS: I'm using the variety wallpaper changer. I don't know if that information is of use.

Comment: I have scavenged for information about this issue in different forums and I have come up with some things we could try to do.
in 13.04 I want you to goto system setting> Software & Updates > additional drivers tab and tell me what driver is selected and those that are not. I just need some more info to come up with an idea and further research the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort. The window is empty and below that, it says "no proprietary drivers are in use".

Comment: goto this [link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2) and download intel graphics installer select the Linux Graphics Installer for Ubuntu* 13.04, 64-bit After you have downloaded, follow the instructions on the page step by step. If you have any problems ask me :) Once you installed everything reboot and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any precautions I could take so that I may reset the status quo ante if it doesn't work?

Comment: You welcome :) You could create a back up just in case

Comment: It seems to have worked. As of now, I can't tell for sure. Thanks!

Comment: The main "answer" is a clarification question, not an answer. Please edit your answer to include the solution to the problem, providing enough details (not just a link) so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Was happy to help :) and i hope it worked!

Comment: The problem still persists. :(

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Firefox solved the issue for me.